# Pass correct image shape to model that uses a conv1d and con2d in the same network

Tags: python, pytorch

so I am trying to implement the VGG network, everything in the paper, but i have when i am using the architecture that has a conv1-255 as part of it network. below is my code

```
def _make_convo_layers(architecture) -> torch.nn.Sequential:
        """
        Create convolutional layers from the vgg architecture type passed in.
        : param architecture:
        """
        layers = []
        in_channels = 3
        for layer in architecture:
            if type(layer) == int:
                out_channels = layer
                layers += [nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1, stride=1), nn.ReLU()]
                # layers.append([nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1, stride=1) + nn.ReLU()])
                in_channels = layer
            elif (layer == 'Conv1-256'):
                out_channels = 256
                layers += [nn.Conv1d(256, out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1, stride=1), nn.ReLU()]
            elif (layer == 'LRN'):
                layers += [nn.LocalResponseNorm(5, alpha=0.0001, beta=0.75, k=1)]
            elif (layer == 'M'):
                layers += [nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)]
        return nn.Sequential(*layers)
```

below is me passing some random data to the model

```
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
print(device)
vgg = VGGNet(config['vgg16-C1']).to(device)
x = torch.randn(1, 3, 224, 224).to(device)
model = vgg(x).to(device)
print(model.shape)
```

below is the error i received when i passed the x variable to the model

```
RuntimeError: Expected 3-dimensional input for 3-dimensional weight [256, 256, 3], but got 4-dimensional input of size [1, 256, 56, 56] instead
```

any help will do, please

Comment: Why are you using a conv1d layer? Where in VGG is this used? I think you might be confusing a 1x1 convolution with a 1D convolution. Can you provide a link to the model you're trying to implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just as jhso commented use are doing this wrong, looking that this VGG explanation on this [VGG](https://neurohive.io/en/popular-networks/vgg16/) page, what you need to do isn't to use a 1D convolution but to perform a convolution operation of kernel size 1 instead of using the original kernel size of 3.

```
def _make_convo_layers(architecture) -> torch.nn.Sequential:
        """
        Create convolutional layers from the vgg architecture type passed in.
        : param architecture:
        """
        layers = []
        in_channels = 3
        for layer in architecture:
            if type(layer) == int:
                out_channels = layer
                layers += [nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1, stride=1), nn.ReLU()]
                in_channels = layer
            elif (layer == 'Conv1-256'):
                out_channels = 256
                layers += [nn.Conv1d(256, out_channels, kernel_size=1, padding=1, stride=1), nn.ReLU()]
            elif (layer == 'LRN'):
                layers += [nn.LocalResponseNorm(5, alpha=0.0001, beta=0.75, k=1)]
            elif (layer == 'M'):
                layers += [nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)]
        return nn.Sequential(*layers)
```